# React: How to print object from state as a table?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in js and react. So I have solutionData object in state and when it gets data from axios it looks like this[image: this]
data can be different everytime. i have a modal to show results and it looks like this: [image]
here is my modal:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this.id)}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}  className="btn-primary">Query result</ModalHeader>
                    <Table className="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Question:</th><td>{this.state.solutionData.title}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Solution:</th><td>{this.state.solutionData.solution}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>data:</th><td>{this.state.solutionData.data}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
```

here in modal i want data to be printed as table but i cant access e.x 'price' like this:

```
this.state.solutionData.data
```

Ideally i want it to look like this:
[image]
So how can I access data in

> solutionData.data

Comment: Use "AgGrid" https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/ It's so useful and you can create a table easily and export it as excel or csv from you json. If you need more help I can send you an example

Comment: @VeyselTuran Thank you its so useful i'll use it, but firstly I wonder how to access the data i want

Comment: As an alternative pure ReactJS and HTML option, you could parse the data string to a js object (JSON.parse(data)), and use {JSON.parse(data).map(row => <tr><td>{row.model}</td> .... </tr>)} to render the table HTML

Comment: It appears that `solutionData.data` is an array. so you can access price via `solutionData.data[0].price` etc.

Comment: Also [S. Strempfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7351472/s-strempfer) and [Baptiste Rieber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15832899/baptiste-rieber) point to good solutions on how to render the data of an array in a table

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an array of objects, so you have to use the `map` function to create a row in your `table` for each object in `data` :

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this.id)}>
  <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this)} className="btn-primary">
    Query result
  </ModalHeader>
  <Table className="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Question:</th>
        <td>{this.state.solutionData.title}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Solution:</th>
        <td>{this.state.solutionData.solution}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>data:</th>
        <td>
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Speed</th>
                <th>Hd</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.solutionData.data.map((d) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{d.model}</td>
                    <td>{d.speed}</td>
                    <td>{d.hd}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </Table>
  <ModalFooter>
    <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>
      Cancel
    </Button>
  </ModalFooter>
</Modal>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const body = {userName:"admin",model:"test"}; your parameters if you use post such as 
axios.post('your url', body)
  .then(response => {
      response.data ==> this is your data
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      console.log("error")
    });
```

Or If you use only Get

```
axios.post('your url')
  .then(response => {
      response.data ==> this is your data
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      console.log("error")
    });
```

Now you have your data with axios. You can set this data in your AgGrid easily If you follow this tutorial https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/

Don't forget to npm install your libraries (axios and Aggrid) to you react project

By the way I highly recommend you to use Aggrid instead of classic table   etc. Aggrid has so many features such as column color, export data, smart filter, multiple filters , column sort and etc..

And If you are still confused how to set data in AgGrid, then let me show you a basic example

```
 <AgGridReact
   enableCellChangeFlash={true}
   enableCellTextSelection={true}
   enableCellExpressions={true}
   pagination={true}
   enableSorting={true}
   enableFilter={true}
   columnDefs={this.state.columnDefinition} //it's your table definition
   rowData={this.state.dataList} // it's your json data
   enableGroupEdit={true}
   enableRangeHandle={true}
   rowHeight={25}
   headerHeight={30}
   onCellClicked={this.GetSelectedMemberInfoOnSearch}
   onColumnResized={true}>
   </AgGridReact>

columnDefinition :[{ headerName: "model", field: "modelNameKey", width: 200, suppressSizeToFit: false },
         { headerName: "speen", field: "speedKey", width: 200, suppressSizeToFit: false },
         { headerName: "hd", field: "hdKey", width: 200, suppressSizeToFit: false }]
```